# Sequelize CLI : sequelize init:models, how does this work?

Tags: sequelize.js

The sequelize init:models  command creates a 'models' folder and adds an index.js.

Can someone explain what exactly this index.js file does and how it fits in to the workflow with Sequelize? I really wish someone would have added some documentation or maybe comments to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it will read everything in the "models" directory, and load them into the db object for you to play with

Let's say you have this subdirectory structure:

```
C:.
│   package.json
│   server.js
│
├───config
│       config.json
│
├───models
│       company.js
│       contact.js
│       index.js  // your index.js
│       job.js
│       task.js
```

Here's a sample company.js. All it does is declared the table for sequelize. contact.js, job.js, and task.js have similar structures.

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Company = sequelize.define("Company", {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    company: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    notes: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  });
  return Company;
};
```

With me so far? Good. Index will read in ALL of the OTHER js files in models subdirectory, and build up a db object for you. You can then use it in your api-routes for the express server. For example...

```
 app.get("/api/company", function (req, res) {
    console.log("At /api/company GET...")
    db.Company.findAll({     // <<------ I just call db.Company... 
      where: {
        user_id: req.user.id
      }
    }).then(function (dbCompany) {
      res.json(dbCompany);
    });
  });
```

If I want to do something with job table instead, I'd just do

```
    db.Job.findAll({     // <<------ I just call db.Job...
```

And similarly, for contact.js and task.js as well.

Without the index.js, I have to refer to EACH of the models separately. Index.js does all that FOR ME into one object, db.(modelname) with which I can then use sequelize functions on.

What's even more fun is when you add models, you don't have to add additional declarations. You can just refer it to your code.

Let's say you just added a 'comment.js' for a comment table with similar structure to above.

You don't need to modify index.js. It will automatically find it upon run-time and add it to the db.(modelname) object for you. So you can add a new route that calls something like this:

```
    db.Comment.findAll({    ...
```

Saves you a lot of drudgeries, basically.

Comment: Thanks Kasey. That makes a lot of sense. Basically its just a dynamic module loader for sequelize models. They could have mentioned this in a single line of comments in the file.